# Getting username in PasswordEncoder

Tags: spring, spring-security

I created my own authentication provider for my spring application, on which I specified the `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder`. I have my users stored in the database with their encrypted passwords (after a database algorithm). For being able to make the authentication, I would need to have access from the `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder` class to the username that is sent for authentication. Can anyone guide me how can I do this? Or is there any other approach?

N.B. I'm using *SpringSecurity* 3.2.

Comment: Please clarify which `PasswordEncoder` you want to use. The `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding` or the `org.springframework.security.crypto.password` one.

Comment: @M.Deinum The new one located under `org.springframework.security.crypto.password` package.

Comment: Could you add that to your question, as that influences how to, possibly, solve that question.

Comment: Also why do you need the username, is that used in the encryption for the password?

Comment: No. But every user has a different encryption salt. So, I would need the encrypted password from database related to user in order to make the authentication.

Comment: Why did you implement your own `AuthenticationProvider`? I would suggest using the old `PasswordEncoder` (despite the fact that it is deprecated), implement a `SaltSource` which retrieves the correct salt for the user, and let Spring Security do the hard stuff. The new bcrypt based classes are intended to work with a system wide salt. Whereas the old `PasswordEncoder` could work with a per user based salt.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! This solved my problem. You can post it as answer for being able to accept it.

Comment: I have the original problem, getting access to the user in `PasswordEncoder`. In my case, it's to re-hash the password when the algorithm/parameters changes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't even care if it's an old question, I've just spent 9 hours trying to figure this out. Might as well leave it here in case someone else stumbles upon this again.

```
String username = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getParameter("username");
```

Using the code above I was able to extract the username from current request.

ATTENTION: You must use the following class `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder`

There was a similar one that was doing me wrong.

Comment: Vote-up for sharing. Thanks.

Comment: i'm getting below exception. Any idea.
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Comment: I changed `getParameter("username")` to `getParameter("userName")` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that User Entered UserName,UserPassword is User,Pwd. 
In order to Authenticate, you can perform the following.

1. Get User Entered Username and Password(User,Pwd).
2. Encode the Pwd using
   `String encodedPassword=passwordEncoder.encode(pwd);`
3. Compare if UserEnteredUserName=DBUserNAme and UserEnteredEncodedPassword==EncodedPasswordInDB, based on match values, you can authenticate the User.

Comment: That's my question. How to get entered Username from my `PasswordEncoder`?

Comment: Password Encoder is only to encode the Password to MD5/SHA or any encryption techniques, it has nothing to do with Username. If yours is a web application, You can get username from Request Parameters.

Comment: I understand. But, is there a way to access this request parameter from `PasswordEncoder`? I'm very new to spring and I don't have yet a clear idea of what happens in the background.